# Java android JsonArray Parser

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse this (for example) :

```
"id":"54f49b4a98686d9478ae44f5",
"title":"Free books",
"slug":"free-books",
"modules":[
[
"list",
{
"slug":"gutenberg",
"title":null,
"books":[]
}
]
]
}
```

How can i get the "books" array ? I use volley library.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a minimal code except, of what you have already tried? This will help others to reproduce and answer this question.

Comment: Hi..I don't know how to do it in volley. But know how to do it with org.json library. Will post the code if you want that

Comment: what kind of request you are making, what i meant to ask is JsonObjectRequest and YoutCustomRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSONArray`. Supposing you have a `JSONObject` called `response` you can get the books as following:

```
 JSONArray modules = response.getJSONArray("modules");
 JSONObject object = modules.getJSONObject(1);
 JSONArray books = object.getJSONArray("book");
```

Take a look here in order to use it with **Volley:** http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/